# How to fix the remove from group function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to make a script that will add and remove computers from a group if they are in a specific ou. What I have so far adds the computers and then when run again it removes all computers from the group. Then run it again and it adds them all back.

It should add the computers that are in the OUs and remove the computers that have been moved out of the OU

```
$OUSTUCOMPUTERS = "OU=STUDENT,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=local"
$OUConstruction = 'BCT','Carpentry','Electrical Occupations','HVAC'
$List = @{}
$Group=[ADSI]"LDAP://CN=CompStuConstruction,OU=Computer Groups,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=local"
foreach ($Shop in $OUConstruction)}
    {$Distinguishedname = "OU="+"$Shop"+","+"$OUSTUCOMPUTERS"

    $OU = [ADSI]"LDAP://$distinguishedname"
    # Enumerate all objects in the OU.
    $arrChildren = $OU.Children
    ForEach ($Child In $arrChildren)
        {
         # Only consider computer objects.
         If ($Child.Class -eq "computer")
            {
             # Add all computers in the OU to the hash table.
             $List.Add($Child.distinguishedName, $True)
             # Check if user a member of the group.
             If ($Group.IsMember($Child.ADsPath) -eq $False)
                 {
                 # Add the computers to the group.
                 $Group.Add($Child.ADsPath)
                 "Added " + $Child.distinguishedName
                 }
            }
        }
    }
         
         
 # Enumerate all members of the group.
 ForEach ($Member in $Group.member)
    {
    # Check if this member object is a computer object in the OU.
    If ($List.ContainsKey($Member)-eq $False)
        {
        # Remove this member from the group.
        $Group.Remove("LDAP://$Member")
        "Removed " + $Member
        }
     }
```

Comment: Huh? `# Only consider user objects.
         If ($Child.Class -eq "computer")`

Comment: Yes it using computer objects not user

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the ActiveDirectory module instead of [ADSI]. Then do

```
    # get your group
    $group = Get-ADGroup -Identity "your group"
    # clear group
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group)
    # add back only correct computer objects
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members @(Get-AdComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "your ou" -SearchScope Subtree)
```